# Is it possible to draw polygons on maps using the flutter_map package?

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I have an application where I need to highlight some states of the country with different colors. Is it possible to do this, using the flutter_map package?

I'm new to flutter, I apologize. But I've searched the library documentation and various places and haven't found anything that can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response.

If you haven't found it already, or for anyone else looking, have a look at the new documentation website: https://docs.fleaflet.dev/usage/layers/polygon-layer.

If you need more help with this package, we'd love to help you on the Discord server (see the README for the join link).